# Function Vector<Vector<...>> : Entries getting changed and i dont know why

Tags: vector, 2d, sprite

I want to initialize a square of textures with sf::sprite elements.

To make the main()-function as clean as possible, I wrote a function in another file, it looks like this:

```
vector<vector<sf::Sprite>> init_board_graphics(int size) {

    sf::Texture _t1;
    sf::Texture _t2;
    _t1.loadFromFile("images/whitefield.png");
    _t2.loadFromFile("images/blackfield.png");

    vector<vector<sf::Sprite>> board;
    //init vector for insert row-values
    vector<sf::Sprite> help_vector;


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        help_vector.clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {

            sf::Sprite insert_element;

            if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                insert_element = sf::Sprite(_t1);
            }
            else {
                insert_element = sf::Sprite(_t2);
            }


            insert_element.setPosition(i * pixel_field, j * pixel_field);
            help_vector.push_back(insert_element);


        }
        board.push_back(help_vector);
    }

    return board;



}
```

When I call the function in main(), everything is fine *at first*, the elements are at the correct positions and the textures are also of correct size.

When I try to debug the next steps, I can observe that the textures of the elements are getting changed in size, even though the next lines have absolutely nothing to do with my object. First, I thought the entries are getting changed because I allocate the entries in the `<vector<vector<sf::sprite>>` - object in a wrong way but I fixed this:

```
if (parameters::visual_output) {
        //Draw field

        
        for (int i = 0; i < size_board; i++) {
            vector<sf::Sprite> help_vec = board[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < size_board; j++) {
                
                window.draw(help_vec[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The textures are still getting changed for some reason. Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the `sf` namespace? You are copying data a lot in this code. If the `Sprite` class does not have an appropriate copy constructor, you will get different objects than you inserted. Start using const references to avoid creating copys. As far as I see, you don't want a vector of textures, anyway. Create the two textures once (e.g. in an array or a separate vector), then have your grid vector only store indices into the first array.

Comment: The sf - namespace is coming from the SFML-2.4.2 library. And thank you, i will try to work with pointers in this case.

Comment: So, now i tried to declare the <vector<vector<sf::Sprite>> object in the namespace so i don't need to copy it, but still the same error occurs.. texture size is jumping from 56x56 to 389423x3483258 and other weird numbers..

Comment: The sprite class seems to keep a reference to the textures. But the textures are destroyed when you leave the function. Store the textures in a non-local variable.

Comment: this fixed it ! thank you!